# ansible zabbix module - loop though templates

Tags: ansible, zabbix, ansible-inventory

i'm having some issued with the ansible zabbix module.
i'm trying to assign multiple templates to a single host.

**my ansible code which doesn't work:**

```
    - name: Create/update Zabbix host
[...]
        link_templates:
          - '{{ zabbix_templates }}'
[...]
```

**code that works:**

```
    - name: Create/update Zabbix host
[...]
        link_templates:
          - "Zabbix agent active"
          - "Linux by Zabbix agent"
[...]
```

**inventory**

```
all:
  hosts:
[...]
  children:
 [...]-cluster:
      hosts:
      [...]
      vars:
        kubernetes_cluster: yes
        cluster_name: [...]-cluster
        OS: ubuntu_22
        zabbix_templates:
          - Zabbix agent active
          - Linux by Zabbix agent
        zabbix_hostgroup: Linux servers
```

the task itself looks very similar to the sample provides here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/zabbix/zabbix_host_module.html
*
[...] = snipped, with real values it works

the error message i'm receiving:

```
fatal: [[...]]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Template not found: ['Zabbix agent active', 'Linux by Zabbix agent']"}
```

i've tried to "reformat" the list multiple times like
- '{{ zabbix_templates | map("from_yaml") | list }}'
and other ways, still no luck. i'm looking for a solution on how to list those vars properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `zabbix_templates` variable is already a list, so you just need to pass it directly to `link_templates`:

```yaml
link_templates: '{{ zabbix_templates }}'
```

Comment: THAT WORKED!, thanks
i think the most obvious thing and i have not tried it.